# Call Realm.init() multiple times

Tags: android, realm

We use realm on the UI thread but also from 2 broadcast receivers. We call init in the receivers to avoid any use case where the receiver will trigger after realm has been cleaned up.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a drawback to doing this?
2. Is there a better way to ensure realm.init() has always been called?

Comment: The second `Realm.init()` should be no-op, so it's ok

Comment: As long as they are in the same process